# foreach loop using $this as key and value

Tags: php

I want to make a foreach loop like this one

```
foreach ($this->data['array'] as $this->data['key'] => $this->data['value'])
{
    echo $this->data['value'];
}
```

Yet the `$this->data['value']` is never created. Why is this and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code in the question doesn't make much sense. why wouldn't you do `$this->data = array_merge($this->data, $this->data['array']);` (if that's the intention)? What is it you're trying to do - what is `$this->data` before, and how do you want it to look after?

Comment: Alright sorry guys I made a mistake in my code, this actually does work. So no problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding, you have a class in which there is a variable or array name $data.

Now, you added an array in $data with an index named 'array', right?
If so, this code will work properly -

```
class myClass{
    public $data = array(); //$data is an array
    
    function print_array(){
     foreach ($this->data['array'] as $this->data['key'] => $this->data['value'])
        {
            echo $this->data['value'];
        }   
    }
}

$ob = new myClass(); // object declaration for your class
array_push($ob->data,'array'); // added a value to the $data array.
$ob->data['array'] = array(); // the newly added value is declared as an index of an array
// Now simply push values to the array named $data['array']
array_push($ob->data['array'],1);
array_push($ob->data['array'],2);
array_push($ob->data['array'],3);

$ob->print_array(); // call the print_array() function. $this will be passed to that function
```

Hope this will help to understand.
If you still have problem, please comment.
To have a clear understanding, you can visit [***this***](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) link. There are lots of simple and interesting examples explained!

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

If:

```
class YourClass {

   private data = array(
     'array' => array(
         'key1' => 'val1',
         'key2' => 'val2', etc.
      )
   );
```

then it should be:

```
foreach ($this->data['array'] as $key => $val)
{
    echo $val;
   // if you want to add keys and vals to data array:
   $this->data[$key] = $val;
}
```

Comment: But I actually want to add the `$key` and `$val` temporary to the `$this->data` array. How would I do that?

Comment: Since you are looping over the keys and values already, they are already part of the array.  If they are not, you cannot loop over them.

Comment: @user3052560 you can check my answer

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake in my code. The original code does actually work

Answer (score 1):

I think `$this` is for current class object reference not for an array

```
foreach ($this->data['array'] as $k => $v)
{
    echo $v;
    $this->data['key'][] = $k;
    $this->data['value'][] = $v;
}
print_r($this->data['key']);
print_r($this->data['value']);
```

Comment: I actually want them to be only available during the foreach loop.

Comment: replace the value of both after loop to null like $this->data['key'] = '';

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake in my code. The original code does actually work